# The best way to create Product Catalog in SharePoint 2013

Tags: office-365, production, catalog

I need to create Product catalog with possibility to upload some excel and pdf files to every product, need to list and display properties of products.

What is the best way to create it in `SharePoint Online 2013`?

Whats the way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom list for products. Create columns for that list, so every item in that list will describe your product (Product Title, Category, description, price, version, anythingelse). 
For every item in sharepoint list you could add attachments.

Answer (score 1):

What about a normal list but make a custom field where you can add the different properties and a field to add attachements (like your pdf/excel)?
This is achieved by adding a 'add attachement field' in list design mode.

Comment: I try to use Documents Set, but I'm looking for better way.

Comment: You can also use a different document library where people add the excel/pdf's and then use the URL to link them in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If it is private site then you can take the advantage of [Cross Site publishing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Activate-the-Cross-Site-Publishing-feature-in-SharePoint-aef0b911-40d7-4d01-a97a-aae8c77dc177?CorrelationId=0106d934-c7ad-45b7-a66b-5c78cb0d2a96&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and [Catalog](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-a-library-or-list-as-a-catalog-in-SharePoint-d1d377f3-77d5-4023-82d6-0a04e8c74ba4?CorrelationId=768c1bec-5b27-4db8-a5a6-90813a5cffb0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) features[1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Activate-the-Cross-Site-Publishing-feature-in-SharePoint-aef0b911-40d7-4d01-a97a-aae8c77dc177?CorrelationId=0106d934-c7ad-45b7-a66b-5c78cb0d2a96&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Once you enable the Cross Site publishing then you can convert any list or library as catalog.

Read this Blog, may be all features will not apply to Online version but still most of it works. http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/02/14/how-to-set-up-a-product-centric-web-site-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx